Why does my object change its visible size when I rotate the simulator screen?
I have a very simple scene in Unity, with a single object (with a SpriteRenderer). When I view it in the Unity simulator, it looks like this:

When I click "rotate", to rotate the simulator screen, it looks like this:

The object area, relative to the screen, is much larger now. Why does this happen, and how can I make the object appear the same size in both cases?
EDIT: I think I understand why. The camera has a property called "Size", which represents its vertical radius (the distance from its center to its top border), and it is set to 5. As the object height is also about 5, it always takes about half the screen height. So it has the same relative height, but not the same relative area.
I still do not know how to change this: what should I do in order to make the person have the same area, relative to the screen?

Unity's cameras maintain a constant height or vertical FoV - the portion of your scene that they see from the top to the bottom - and vary only their width / horizontal FoV as the aspect ratio of the screen changes.
In your first image, the figure is about 50% the height of the camera's view.
In your second image, the figure is still about 50% the height of the camera's view.
We can see this by overlaying your two example images:

So what's happened in the portrait mode view is that the areas to the left and right have been cropped-out, while preserving the height of the figure relative to the height of the display.
This is the default because it's usually what we want for 3D games: players with widescreen monitors should see more on the left and right, not less on top and bottom. For mobile games, sometimes you want to customize it.
If you want the opposite behaviour, maintaining the horizontal extent of the visible scene and cropping or extending the top and bottom, all you have to do is tell Unity that's what you want.
If you want to scale to keep the total area of the visible scene constant instead, cropping a mix of the width/height as needed, you could modify the script like so:
// Units: m²
public float desiredSceneArea = 16*9;

void Update() {
    // Units: pixels²
    float screenArea = Screen.width * Screen.height;

    // Units: m/pixel
    float ratio = Mathf.Sqrt(desiredSceneArea / sceneArea);

    // Units: m
    float desiredHalfHeight = 0.5f * ratio * Screen.height;

    _camera.orthographicSize = desiredHalfHeight;
}

(This is using update since Unity still doesn't seem to expose a simple window resize event - though you can use the UI system and hook OnRectTransfromDimensionsChange to approximate that)
You can also make use of a UI Canvas, which offers a variety of ways to control how the canvas and its contents resize and rearrange themselves to fit on screens of different sizes. That might be more appropriate if you're trying to design an interface, rather than a view into a world/scene.

Thanks! Using the script you linked to, the person looks much larger in the horizontal view. So I adapted the script a bit to work by sqrt(width*height) rather than width or height alone, and it works perfectly.
